# Set of rapidly increasing functions is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $$ S=\{f \colon \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R} \mid f(n+1) \ge 2^{f(n)} \}.$$
How to prove $S$ is uncountable ?

I tried proving by contradiction, but not able to construct a new function different from the countable collection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many choices are there for $f(m)$ where $m \in \{0,1\}$, whichever is the least element of $\Bbb{N}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could define recursively $f(n+1) = 2^{f(n)}+c$, where $c$ is any real greater than $0$, and since $\mathbb{R}^+$  is uncountable you are done.

Following this, I'm going to build a set of functions $F=\bigcup\limits_{i>0} \{f_i \}$:

1. For every $i$: $f_i(0)=1$
2. $f_i(n+1) = 2^{f_i(n)}+i$

First, notice how this set of functions satisfy your rapidly-increasing restriction; second, there is an $f_i$ for every $i\in\mathbb{R}^+$ so the cardinality of $F$ must be uncountable. For a concrete example: $f_1(0)=1$, and $f_1(1)=2^1+1=3$, $f(2)=2^3+1=9$ and so on.

---

A non-constructive proof via diagonalization would be as follows:

Assume $S$ is countable, and order $f, g \in S$ by $f \ll g \iff \forall x f(x)<g(x)$. Notice how under this definition it is not always true that $f \ll g$ or $f=g$ or $f\gg g$. So this is a partial ordering. Now pick a maximal chain $f_i$ and define $\hat f(1)=f_1(1)$ and $\hat f(i)=f_i(i) + \left[f_{i+1}(i)-f_{i}(i)\right]/2$.You can check that this $\hat f$ satisfies the rapidly-increasing restriction and it is different from every $f_i$ at $i$. A contradiction!

Comment: Or require $c=1$, but exploit the fact $f(1)$ can take uncountably many values.

Comment: @Shiranai How you will define $f(1)$ ?

Comment: @Manoj it can be any positive number

Comment: @Shiranai I'm sorry, but I did not get your logic, can you elaborate little with more.

Comment: Sure, I just expanded on my answer, check it out @Manoj

Comment: @Shiranai got it, thanks.

Comment: No problem, also added another proof :) A diagonalization one this time, it's a bit more complicated than the previous one

Comment: Hey I posted a similar answer to yours.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually show that the set $S=\{f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} : f(n+1) \geq  2^{f(n)}\}$ is uncountable. For each given $n$, let $A_n \subset S$ denote those functions such that $f(n+1) > 1 + 2^{2^{f(n)}}$. We have a surjection $g:S \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by mapping $f \in S$ to $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : f \in A_n\}$.

Comment: Why you are taking $f(n+1)>1+2^{2^{f(n)}}$ ?

Comment: You can simplify this construction to simply $f\in A_n\iff f(n+1)>2^{f(n)}$. At each $n$, $f(n+1)$ can be freely chosen among all values that are at least $2^{f(n)}$, so the set of all such functions is isomorphic to ${\Bbb N}^{\Bbb N}$.

Answer (score 5):

I think a simpler proof is to notice that if we restrict the predicate to $f(n+1)=2^{f(n)}$, every function $f:\mathbb N\to blah$ is determined by its value $f(0)$. Setting $blah=\mathbb R$, $f(0)$ can then take $\mathbb R$-many values, so the set of all such functions is uncountable. Then the obvious injection from the previous set of functions to yours proves that the latter is uncountable.

---

Shiranai's answer is similar, except they fix the first (or $n$-many) values, so $f(n+1)$ is required to be greater than or equal to $2^{f(n)}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could come up with a proof by contradiction. It also works if you replace $\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb N$ in the definition of $S$. (The version with $\Bbb R$ is too easy as $f(0)$ can take continuum many values, as in the answers by palmpo and by Shiranai. 
The answer by MathematicsStudent1122 already shows that we can replace $\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb N$, but I will use a proof by contradiction and diagonalization.)

Let $S=\{f \colon \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N} \mid f(n+1) \ge 2^{f(n)} \}$ where $\Bbb N$ is the set $\{0,1,2,...\}$ of all non-negative integers. 
Suppose $S$ were countable, say $S=\{f_n : n\in\Bbb N\}$. Define a new function $f$ by 
$f(0)=f_0(0)+1$ and, recursively, $f(n+1)=\max\{f_{n+1}(n+1)+1,2^{f(n)}\}$. Then $f(n+1)\ge 2^{f(n)}$, hence $f\in S$, but on the other hand for every $n$ we have $f(n)\ge f_n(n)+1>f_n(n)$, hence $f\notin S$. This contradiction shows that $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: @ManojKumar by recursive construction of $f$ we have $f(n+1)=\max\{f_{n+1}(n+1)+1,2^{f(n)}\}\ge 2^{f(n)}$. That is, once $f(n)$ is defined, then you define $f(n+1)$ to be the bigger of the two numbers $f_{n+1}(n+1)+1$ and $2^{f(n)}$, so in particular $f(n+1)\ge 2^{f(n)}$.

Comment: Ah! Great that's what I want.

Comment: I could have accepted this as answer to my question, but I already accepted other one.

Answer (score 1):

The powerset of any set has greater cardinality than the original set.

Every nontrivial sunset of $\mathbb{N}$ can be mapped to by some function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

So now you just need to show each nontrivial subset of $\mathbb{N}$ can correspond with a particular rapidly growing function.

Start with one rapidly growing function F. For each subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with n elements and largest element m, construct a degree m polynomial with n terms with exponents corresponding to the members of $\mathbb{N}$. Multiply this polynomial by F and you have a new rapidly growing function.